# Самый быстрый метод разархивации файла

Tags: оптимизация, zip

Встала задача, что нужно разархивировать огромное количество (>4тб) архивов, в которых очень много маленьких файлов.

Перепробовал и 7z, и zipFile, peaZip (запускал через среду программирования через консоль по сути) и д.р. Но скорость совсем не радует.

Как можно ускорить процесс? Какие есть аналоги и альтернативы?

Comment: Узкое место - чтение? распаковка? запись на диск?

Comment: Прикинул: при среднем коэффициенте сжатия 2 и средней скорости записи на одиночный винчестер 50 мегабайт в секунду (что в общем-то довольно оптимистично при большом количестве файлов, особенно при большом количестве файлов в каталогах) процесс записи 8 тб на HDD займёт не менее двух суток при условии, что читаем архив с другого локального диска. Не спешите. Быстро не выйдет. Это не скорость маленькая, это данных много. Варианты решения, скорее всего, будут неприемлемы и по стоимости, и по сроку поставки.

Comment: А что насчет gzip и tar? Может они побыстрее будут?